# Conferences,Meetings

Tags: networking

Hi everyone~I'm very glad to be here and to be one of YOU!
Would you please amswer me,Are there any Sound/Music Design Conferences? And how can I participate them? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

School of Sound and AES are good ones. Select the ones that you want to attend to, depending on what you aim to get from it.

Are you looking after networking, meeting new people from industry? Or do you actually want to learn stuff?

Both will meet your expectations to some content, but I also suggest to attend **conferences of other fields**, such as video production or motion graphics. It creates a whole another level of networking opportunities, plus you get to know the expectations of a different profile of artists. This will help you understand your clients better. It did in my case.

Comment: You are a genius. 

Comment: +1! I have gotten more out of attending other semi-related meetups with game designers, app developers, motion designers etc. The networking is great, plus getting an inside look at their workflows adds a ton of insider perspective. I went to an iOS developer meetup (I couldn't program my way out of a wet paper bag) and it opened a whole bunch of doors for me. 

Answer (score 2):

I've heard good things about [this](http://www.schoolofsound.co.uk/) one.

[AES](http://ttp://www.aes.org/) is also great.

Comment: I thought of a couple others. There's been a Kyma symposium the last few years. Also, MPSE holds a "sound show" every once and awhile in LA. http://www.mpse.org/ 

Answer (score 1):

Justin names good ones. I've been to both the School of Sound and AES, and both were great in their own right.

The School of Sound was super inspirational, while AES was fantastic in a more practical/grounded kind of way. AES was great for networking and checking out exhibitors and gear too.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the Jeff McIlwain "L'usine"? If it is you, you do some nice work man.

Everyone else posted the obvious stuff related to your question. Other than that, this is the closest thing we have to a convention, and it's a lot better in most ways actually.

So I guess that just leaves me with: Nice to meet you and welcome aboard.

Answer (score 0):

The audio day at the Develop Conference in Brighton (UK) is a good one, if you're based in Europe, and (aspire to) work in videogames.